# Platform-independent font directory?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, macos, fonts

Where are fonts stored on Windows, macOS, and Linux?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is one of those 'simple' problems that could have an over-the-top solution depending on the need. Linux distributions don't use any specific font management making fonts across Linux flavours inconsistent, very configurable, and influenced by many factors including desktop environment, remote services, and more. A Linux distribution may not have any font directories specified at all (e.g., on a headless RTOS installation or using an [X Font Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Font_Server) that serves up fonts remotely).

**Font directory locations**

- **Windows** (newer than 3.1)

  - `%WINDIR%\fonts`
- **Mac OSX**

  - `/System/Library/Fonts` - Fonts necessary for the system. Do not touch these.
  - `/Library/Fonts` - Additional fonts for all users. Fonts that are to be used by other applications, in general.
  - `~/Library/Fonts` - User-specific fonts.
  - `/Network/Library/Fonts` - Fonts shared for users on a network.
- **Linux**

  - `/usr/share/fonts` - Common location across many Linux distributions.
  - `/usr/local/share/fonts` - Common location across many Linux distributions.
  - `~/.fonts` - User-specific fonts.

Some Linux systems may have configured font directories in the following files:

- `/etc/fonts/fonts.conf`
- `/etc/fonts/local.conf`

For example, run `grep "<dir>" /etc/fonts/fonts.conf`, which may show:

```xml
<dir>/usr/share/fonts</dir>
<dir>/usr/local/share/fonts</dir>
<dir>~/.fonts</dir>
```

**Checking for environment**

You can check various platforms via the use of macros defined for specific environments.

- Windows - `#if defined(_WIN32)`

  - `_WIN32` is defined for both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows.
- Mac OSX - `#if defined(_APPLE_) && defined(_MACH_)`

  - `_APPLE_` is defined for all Apple computers, and `_MACH_` is defined if the system supports Mach system calls, *a la* Mac OSX
- Linux (generic) - `#if defined(linux) || defined(__linux)`

**Resources**

- [Mac OS X: Font Locations](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2435?viewlocale=en_US)
- [How to install or remove a font in Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314960)
- [Predefined C/C++ Macros Project](http://predef.sourceforge.net/index.php)
- [Font Configuration: Arch Linux Wiki](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Font_Configuration)
- [Fonts: Ubuntu Linux Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Fonts)
- [Fonts: GNU/Debian Linux Wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/Fonts)
- [Fonts Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/international_language_support_guide/fonts) (and CentOS 5)
- [X Font Server System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Font_Server)

Comment: Note that on Win Vista and newer, fonts can be installed anywhere, not just the `%WINDIR%\Fonts` directory. The registry holds the install locations.

Answer (score 1):

That's assuming the target OS **has** a font folder. For example, it's quite feasible for a Linux installation to be console-only and not have a font directory at all.

Anyways, my best *guess* is that there is no platform independent way. You can write your own platform independent function, but within it will have to check the current OS (via some IFDEF's, I cannot say what) and then call the right function. But again - I wouldn't be so sure you can obtain it under Linux at all.

Comment: To make matters worse, even on a unix system with XWindows, the fonts could be getting generated mainly through a font server, which could be on a remote machine and completely opaque/unavailable to the client programs.